# push items in an array with else

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In my typescript code, I have an array of products

```
products = [10,25,45,89];
```

I am making a service call to retrieve client who made a purchase on the product

```
products.forEach(x => 
  this.clientService.getclientOrdersByProduct(clientId, x)
  .subscibe(s=>{ 
     if (s){ 
       this.clientOrders.push(s);
     } else{ 
       // add the product id
     }
   })
);
```

the problem is I want to add an else and push product Id in clientOrders. ClientOrders class is like this

```
export interface ClientAccount{  product?: Product; ....}
```

how can I achieve this in the else?

Thanks

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. What do you mean by "add an else"?

Comment: Please include more information in your question, it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I have added the comment on where I want the else to be.

Comment: you mean `(s){ foo; } else { push into clientOrders }` ?

Comment: correct @JacopoSciampi

Comment: declare the array -> `clientOrder: ClientAccount[] = [];` and then in the else -> `this.clientOrder.push({product: something, productId: x);`

Comment: Can you please post a sample output?

Comment: @NikhilAggarwal: which sample?

Comment: @JackM - With given input, how will the output look like with let us say only 2 products have orders and rest do not

Comment: @JacopoSciampi thanks it is working, If you add it to the solution I will mark as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the interface is something like that:

```
export interface ClientAccount{  
  product?: Product;
  productId: number;
  ...
}
```

you can do this:

create an array of clientOrder:

```
clientOrder: ClientAccount[] = [];
```

in the `for`

```
products.forEach(x => 
  this.clientService.getclientOrdersByProduct(clientId, x)
  .subscibe(s=>{ 
     if (s){ 
       this.clientOrders.push(s);
     } else{ 
       this.clientOrder.push({product: **something**, productId: x);
     }
   })
);
```

`something` is in bold because I've no idea what kind of data are you getting from that subscription.